# How to add a fixed key for each element of list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
student = ["James", "Abhinay", "Peter"]
```

I don't know how I can add a fixed key for each element of list in python?

what I want:

```
[{'name': 'James'}, {'name': 'Abhinay'}, {'name': 'Peter'}]
```

Comment: resist the urge to tag with both python 2 and 3. afaik, dictionaries behave a bit differently in 3.x, so the distinction might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [{'name': x} for x in student]
[{'name': 'James'}, {'name': 'Abhinay'}, {'name': 'Peter'}]
>>>
```

Or `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: {'name': x}, student))
[{'name': 'James'}, {'name': 'Abhinay'}, {'name': 'Peter'}]
>>>
```